# Best fit line for a degree 2 polynomial regression

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to create the best fit line between 2 points x and y using the polyfit function in numpy with degree 2.

```
fit = polyfit(x, y, 2)
fit_fn = poly1d(fit)

plot(x, y, 'k.', x, fit_fn(x), '--r', linewidth=1)
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
```

I'm bit confused why is the best fit line so thick instead of being a simple line.
Do you thing I'm doing something wrong in the code?

[image: fit with fat line]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your `x` is not sorted.  Try

```
plot(x, y, 'k.', sort(x), fit_fn(sort(x)), '--r', linewidth=1)
```

plot "connects the dots" from `(x_0, fit_fn(x_0))` to `(x_1, fit_fn(x_1))`.  If your `x`'s aren't sorted, then the line is zig-zagging all over the place, making it look thick.

Comment: If `x` is very large, you are wasting time sorting it twice, I'd say `xs = np.sort(x)` then `plot(x, y, 'k.', xs, fit_fn(xs), ...)`